# tcblisting box w/ minted shows incorrect listings

Tags: tcolorbox, minted, tcblisting

When using one of the tcblisting boxes for code and comments with minted, I often have problems getting the code snippets to show up. Previously, I used listings and had no problems, but the second I moved to minted for better features, this error began to show - the listing code box would display the last minted box instead of the correct code snippet.

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{minted}{python}
def function(n):
    print(n)
\end{minted}

\begin{tcbdefinition}[name = Test, minted language = python]{
This is a function that takes in argument \mintinline{text}{n}, prints it, and returns it. \mintinline{text}{test}
}
def function(n):
    print(n)
    return n
\end{tcbdefinition}
```

The tcblisting box code for reference:

```
    % code def
    \newtcblisting[auto counter, number within=section, list inside=definitionlist]{tcbdefinition}[2][]{%
        colback=red!5, colbacktitle=red!20, coltitle=black,
        frame hidden, arc=2pt, titlerule=0pt, toptitle=2pt, bottomtitle=2pt,
        fonttitle=\bfseries, breakable, enhanced, parbox=false,
        segmentation style={solid, draw=red!20, line width=1pt},
        comment and listing,
        title=Definition~\thetcbcounter,
        comment={#2},#1
    }
    % code example
    \newtcblisting[auto counter, number within=section, list inside=examplelist]{tcbexample}[2][]{%
    colback=gray!5, colbacktitle=gray!40, coltitle=black,
    frame hidden, arc=2pt, titlerule=0pt, toptitle=2pt, bottomtitle=2pt,
    fonttitle=\bfseries, breakable, enhanced, parbox=false,
    segmentation style={solid, draw=gray!20, line width=1pt},
    comment and listing,
    title=Example~\thetcbcounter,
    comment={#2},#1
    }

% generate Name
    \pgfkeysifdefined{/tcb/name}{\fail}{
    \tcbset{
    name/.style={after title={: #1}}}
    }
```

If anyone has also seen similar bugs or has any idea how I can fix this/report this so it can get fixed, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Please combine your code snippets into a complete example that starts with `\documentclass` and contains a `document` environment. I can't reproduce your problem with `tcolorbox` 2022/01/07 v5.0.2 and `minted` 2021/12/24 v2.6. What's your versions? Also you may want to clear temp `_minted-xxx` directory.

Comment: How do you clear the temp minted directory and check the package versions? On WSL currently and I used `sudo apt install texlive` to get the packages. Also, I don't really understand why a whole new document would clear things up as snippets vs. a whole document doesn't really change things for me - it still gives me the same issues. It seems to be a bit of a heisenbug that's getting very irritating to work with.

Comment: Add `\listoffiles` to preamble and you'll find package version info near the end of `.log` file. By default `minted` will create temp directory `_minted-main` if your tex file named `main.tex`. A complete example helps others to help you, eg they can simply copy-paste to run and test example locally.

Comment: Sounds great, thanks! I'll keep that in mind for the future. I noticed that minted works with my regular tcbtheorem boxes, so this indirectly solves my problem as I just realized I don't need to use this workaround type of tcblisting box.